# Compile with different instruction set for different files in CMAKE

Tags: cmake

I am trying to build this example: https://xsimd.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/dispatching.html

which uses xsimd architecture dispatching. I added the calls to the 2 functions in 2 separate files:

**xsimd-avx.hpp**

```
#include "sum.hpp" 
 
template float sum::operator()<xsimd::avx2, float>(xsimd::avx2, float const*, unsigned);
```

**xsimd-sse.hpp**

```
#include "sum.hpp"
 
template float sum::operator()<xsimd::sse2, float>(xsimd::sse2, float const*, unsigned);
```

I want to set up my cmake project such that I compile `xsimd-avx.hpp` with the `-mavx` compiler flag and xsimd-sse2.hpp with the `-msse2` flag. How do I enable that?

I have tried:

```
add_library(xsimd-avx OBJECT src/xsimd-avx.hpp) 

add_library(xsimd-sse OBJECT src/xsimd-sse.hpp)

set_target_properties (xsimd-avx PROPERTIES COMPILE_FLAGS "-mavx2")

set_target_properties (xsimd-sse PROPERTIES COMPILE_FLAGS "-msse2")
```

but it doesn't work. The avx instructions are not recognised.

Comment: Well first you should rename files containing explicit instantiation definitions with .cpp extension. Then, no need to use OBJECT targets, you can set PROPERTIES per source file with https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/set_source_files_properties.html

Comment: If cmake sees a `.hpp` file, it assumes it's a header and doesn't compile that file. If you want to change this behaviour you could use `set_source_files_properties(....hpp ....hpp  PROPERTIES LANGUAGE CXX)`, but my recommendation would be to simply rename the files to `.cpp` or `.cxx` files. When setting the compile flags for a whole target, `target_compile_options` is preferable, but you can set the option on a per-source file level using `set_property(SOURCE ....hpp APPEND PROPERTY COMPILE_OPTIONS "-mavx2")`